# LINQ Operation GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView which populates

```
ID  Name    City
1   Bobby   AAA
2   Laura   BBB
3   Ilisha  CCC
```

I want to get an enumerable collection something like following

```
var  Query= from p in GridView1.Rows 
   select new { User_ID=p.ID,User_Name=p.Name,User_City=p.City }.ToList();
```

How to get it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use the actual object that the grid row represents, then you need to access the `DataItem` property of the row.

```
var query = from p in GridView1.Rows.Select(r => r.DataItem as YourDataType)
            select new 
            { 
                User_ID=p.ID,
                User_Name=p.Name,
                User_City=p.City 
            }.ToList()
```

(`YourDatatype` here represents whatever type of object you're expecting the grid to be bound to).

Answer (score 2):

To get an enumerable collection, all you need to do is cast the GridViewRowCollection to an IEnumerable.

```
 IEnumerable<GridViewRow> rows = GridView1.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
```

Comment: I just ran in to this, do you know why we have to cast this in the first place?  `GridViewRowCollection` inherits from `IEnumerable`. Shouldn't we be able to to `LINQ` directly?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right Track with the query.

The only suggestion would be to try and use the original source which binds to the gridview instead of relying on gridview.DataSource